# Custom hardware button events/intents

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a custom device with a custom button and I need to handle an hardware Button Events/Intents:
every time I press the button it generates a PTT Press Action and I need to open my custom application, is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by custom device, you mean custom AOSP. Then make sure, it's button bound to events, this should be done with low level device driver configuration. And it's complicated work. Next, make sure you receive your click in next events.

Try to either use dispatch key event on Activity work:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP){

         enter();

            return true;
    }}
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
};
```

On on key event with Android `View` which is in focus.

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
         /* This is a sample for handling the Enter button */
      return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```